# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER when using form_with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

i am learning ruby on rails and i have a code that is suppose to update a model instance parameters in rails but i get **syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER** when ever i try to put the method :patch and get a missing method if i don't put it:

this is the line of code:

```
<%= form_with model: @request  method: :"patch" url: requests_update_path(:id => @request.id) do |f|%>
```

i had put and delete parenthesis, comas, form_tag , form, method and nothing seams to help :(

pd: the ruby version i am currently using is 2.6.6

Comment: thanks both of you, i was sure i have tried that but now it doesn't give me syntax error so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing commas (as the comments suggest), also im not sure that `:"patch"`will work, try `method: :patch`.

you can find many examples/explanations [here](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with) should you need to change it further and need inspiration

```rb
<%= form_with model: @request, method: :patch, url: requests_update_path(:id => @request.id) do |f|%>
```

Comment: FYI: `:"symbol"` is perfectly fine syntax for symbols, allowing symbols with spaces inside, like `:"I am a symbol"`. Such symbols are really just more of a curiosity than anything useful. Sometimes it can be used to create symbols with interpolation `:"some_#{name}"` which avoids creating interim string object in memory.